# c# mysql update single row

Tags: c#, mysql

This is the code. I want it to update this uses 0 and koffekeys, some how it cant look up val..

```
     string Query = "UPDATE `users.db`.`userslogged` SET `uses`='0' WHERE `koffekeys`='@val'";
        string constring = "server=127.0.0.1;User Id=root;password=******;Persist Security Info=True;database=users";
        MySqlConnection conDatabase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
        MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDatabase);

        cmdDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val", this.textBox1.Text);

        conDatabase.Open();
        cmdDataBase.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conDatabase.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Ouch... might want to edit out your Database's root password... Never post real connection strings!

Comment: Whats the question...

Comment: Thanks Evan, althought its just on a dummy mysql server. 

Martin the question is why cant @val see the value in textbox1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the reason why the parameter is not working is because it was surrounded by single quotes. Parameters are identifiers and not string literals.

Remove the single quotes and it will work.

```
string Query = @"UPDATE `users.db`.`userslogged` 
                 SET    `uses`='0' 
                 WHERE  `koffekeys` = @val";
```

When an identifier is wrapped with single quotes, it is not an identifer anymore but already a string literal.